# Choosing a different executable in bash

Tags: bash, path, makefile, solaris

When I want to run `make` to generate some executables it always uses the Sun `make` located
at `/usr/local/bin/make` rather than GNU make which can be found at `/usr/sfw/bin/gmake`.

How can I tell the OS to use GNU make rather than Sun's? Do I need to overwrite the path somehow?

Comment: With 2 separately named programs, I'm confused about why there is a problem. If you type `make` on the command line, why would it run `gmake`? Are you saying that you have typed `gmake` and it runs `make`?

Answer (score 5):

For two executables named identically, reorder paths in the `PATH` variable, since the first match will be used.

Otherwise, define an alias in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias make="/usr/sfw/bin/gmake"
```

Or a function:

```
make() { /usr/sfw/bin/gmake "$@"; }
```

Note, that aliases work only in interactive mode. Scripts will not see them. Use functions in such case.

Answer (score 2):

you can link /usr/sfw/bin/gmake to /usr/bin for example as long as the directory where you link it to is before /usr/local/bin in the PATH variable
thus

```
    cd /usr/bin
    ln -s /usr/sfw/bin/gmake make
```

just be sure there is no make already in the path.
otherwise you always can call gmake instead of make to use gnu-make and leave make for the sun-version-make.

otherwise you can use the alias as in the previous post

Comment: Putting extra stuff into `/usr/bin` is not such a good idea - leave that area to package management, which may one day opt to install a `make` there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're manually running the make command, then simply type `gmake` instead of `make`. It will run the GNU version (assuming that your `PATH`) variable is set properly.

If there's an IDE or some other tool that's invoking `make`, you need to tell it to use gmake rather than make and the way to do that depends on which tool you're using.

Comment: Another possibility along those lines: If you have a recursive makefile that is invoking "make" later, even when you start it with "gmake", then modify the makefile to replace the hardcoded "make" inside it with "$(MAKE)".