# Setting up Apache Tomcat in Cygwin

Tags: java, tomcat, cygwin

I'm trying to set up Apache Tomcat on Cygwin and when I run the configtest.sh script, I get this error.  My environment variables all appear to be correct, but when java complains about not finding classes, it tries looking in some weird paths like it's starting from the current directory:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   C:\cygwin\usr\local\apache-tomcat-7.0.26
Using CATALINA_HOME:   C:\cygwin\usr\local\apache-tomcat-7.0.26
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: C:\cygwin\usr\local\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\temp
Using JRE_HOME:        C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
Using CLASSPATH:       C:\cygwin\usr\local\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\cygwin\usr\local\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\bin\tomcat-juli.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/startup/Bootstrap
   <<No stacktrace available>>
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap not found in java.lang.ClassLoader$1{urls=[
file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/bin/C,
file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/bin/\cygwin\usr\local\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\bin\bootstrap.jar;C,
file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/bin/\cygwin\usr\local\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\bin\tomcat-juli.jar], parent=null}
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:531)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:341)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader$1.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1112)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:293)
Configuration error detected!
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to mix Windows and Cygwin paths.

Comment: my paths should be getting passed to java as Windows paths though.  That's what the startup script does.  So I don't know why they show up all funky in the stack trace.

Comment: Actually, I see the problem.  It's that $_RUNJAVA calls /usr/bin/java instead of my windows jre installation.  I don't know what to do about this though.

Comment: There's a couple different solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913894/choosing-a-different-executable-in-bash

Comment: I fixed it.  I was being an idiot and not realizing that I was setting my JRE_HOME variable after _RUNJAVA gets set with the default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file URLs shown in the stacktrace don't look correct. The classpath looks like it was split by the unix path separator, not the windows one, and the slashes are windows slashes, not unix ones.

```
file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/bin/C,
file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/bin/\cygwin\usr\local\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\bin\bootstrap.jar;C,
file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/bin/\cygwin\usr\local\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\bin\tomcat-juli.jar
```

If I were you, I'd try to set any path related environment variables in cygwin rather than rely on windows, since you are running a bash script.  You can make the cygwin value dependent on the windows variables by using the cygpath program:

```
export CLASSPATH=`cygpath $CLASSPATH`
```

Comment: the startup script does this:
``CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --windows "$CLASSPATH"` ``
before passing the path to java

Comment: --windows prints the windows version of the path. I'd be surprise

Comment: yeah, cygpath was working correctly, but I figured out that _RUNJAVA in the startup script was calling my cygwin port of java rather than my windows installation.  So it was passing a windows version path to a linux program.  I changed the startup script so that _RUNJAVA points to my windows installation of java, and everything works fine now.